# Demand forecasting task without demand column

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, python, forecasting

I apologize for the naive question in advance, I'm completely new to forecasting. I have a Machine Learning demand forecasting task for a healthcare service. I have some columns such as date, diagnosis, hospital etc and each row represents a particular time that this service was used. However, from a search on the internet, all the datasets of similar nature also include a demand (sales) column that is being predicted. How should I approach this forecasting problem if I haven't got such a column? My task is to make weekly and monthly forecasting models for this service in python.

Comment: Are you trying to forecast for a specific 'service' such as a x-ray or something? Or is just total services at hospital A.  Or even total services across all hospitals?  Sounds like once you figure out that level then you could just get the counts per week/month and level and feed that to a model for starts.

Comment: What Tylerr says. If you have timestamps of when a service or product was *demanded*, you can simply aggregate these demand instances within daily, weekly or monthly buckets, and there is your demand column.